# Why I read in output in the section constraint t#0#1 and not t[1][1] in CPLEX?

Tags: output, constraints, cplex

If I have a variable like Y[i][j] and t[i][j] where  i=1..20 (I), j=1..10 (J) and this constraint

```
forall (i in I)
  forall (j in J)
t[i][j] <= Y[i][j]
```

Why in output if I go to see the constraint is of the type t#0#1 <= Y#0#1 when it really should be: t[1][1]<=Y[1][1] ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you have arrays with many values , opl cplex will change the indexes in order to save memory but you can tell cplex not to do that by changing the setting

Let me quote documentation:

> More about the “Big map naming threshold” option
>
> The setting determines how the map name is printed, both on most
> screen outputs and in CPLEX exported files:
>
> •If the map is considered big (by default, greater than or equal to
> 100), then numerical indices are used. For example, in the LP file
> exported from the nurses example:
>
> id1985: costByDepartments#0 - 150 nurseAssignments#0#0
>
> - 168 nurseAssignments#1#0 - 102 nurseAssignments#2#0 ...
>
> •If the map is considered small (by default, smaller than 100), then
> the real index values are used:
>
> id1985: costByDepartments("Emergency")
>
> - 150 nurseAssignments({"Anne",11,1,25})({"Emergency","Monday",2,8,3,5})
> - 168 nurseAssignments({"Bethanie",4,5,28})({"Emergency","Monday",2,8,3,5})
>   ...
>
> This option is currently used to switch between short and full map
> item names, for example, the names of decision variables or submaps.
> Big maps have short names.

Suppose you want to change this threshold. You can write

```
execute
{
thisOplModel.settings.bigmapthreshold=1000000;

}
```